# How to change the width of the boxplot frame in R

Tags: r, border, boxplot

I am trying to change the thickness of the border containing the boxplot figure. Is there a way to do this in R? Attached is the image with an arrow pointing to the border that I am talking about whose thickness I would like to change [illustration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzml5.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Boxplot has a width parameter. Are you plotting to your workspace or to a file? It won't work in RStudio, because the plot will adapt to the size of the plotting window.

Comment: I am using RStudio. Actually I used the wrong word, I meant the thickness of the border, not the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by overwriting the existing box with a heavier one.

```
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species)
box(lwd=3)
```

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: Hi G5W, I came across that parameter, but that will change the thickness of the individual boxes making up the boxplot, I want to change the thickness of the outer enclosing box.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood the first time.  I have edited the response.

Comment: Great! That is what I was trying to do. Thanks!